# Jumping in jQuery width animation

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle, padding

I'm having trouble working out why my animation is jumping. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/9F5DK/5/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// Animate the single page nav
    jQuery("a#post-nav-next").hover(

          function(){ 

            jQuery("a#post-nav-next span").stop(true, true).animate({width: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"});

        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Follow up. It seems it's being caused by the text reflowing as the span closes. How to fix this? Perhaps hide it at close?

Comment: Hmm... still no worky [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9F5DK/6/) with overflow: hidden

Comment: my guess would be that it's because you're animating the text and not the surrounding container.  but I'm interested in the answer as well.  i'll wait for someone smarter than me to answer.

Comment: also I don't know if you've noticed yet but your container being an anchor tag, not only is your Home text underlined there is also an extra underline under your 'box'.

Comment: yeah that styling is overwritten in another part of the stylesheet :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I spent some time figuring this out.  Normally I don't like altering the original html javascript/jquery this much and if this doesn't work for you then I apologize.  Here is a JSFiddle that does what you want I think...

http://jsfiddle.net/LqHwk/1/

One nice thing about this set up is you can add as many

```
<div class="post-nav-next">
```

as you wish inside the wrapper and they will all work the same

BTW I highly recommend using the jquery plugin [hoverIntent](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent).

Comment: AWESOME!!!! Thanks kasdega! I just started looking at this again and that is a better solution than I got to :-) I like hoverintent too

Answer (score 2):

Issues I see:

Setting a height or width on an inline `<a>` or `<span>` tag in your CSS or in your animation.  Read [this article](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/) for the issues with trying to set height or width on inline tags.  This applies to both your CSS and your animation.  If you want to animate width, I think you're going to need to do it on a block element.

It seems to me that the animation may be getting confused by the toggle for width and opacity.  Perhaps you'd be better off specifying both callbacks for hover and specifying the animation start and stop points more directly rather than leaving the toggle method to having to figure out what the start and stop points should be.

For example, without redoing the HTML to be block elements (which I think is required to animate width reliably), here's a smooth animation on just the opacity.  I've set the starting point in the CSS to the desired starting opacity and I've stopped using toggle to set the animation and am setting it explicitly.  I'm not sure this is required, but it sures removes the ambiguity from what toggle is going to try to guess what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/r2cdn/ (opacity animation only in this jsfiddle, both animations included in jsfiddle below).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// Animate the single page nav
    jQuery("a#post-nav-next").hover(function(){ 
            jQuery("a#post-nav-next span").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "1.0"});
        }, function() {
            jQuery("a#post-nav-next span").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "0"});
        }
    );
});
```

For the toggle of the width, what two states were you hoping to toggle between?  That was not clear to me as a human and probably not clear to jQuery.toggle() either.  If, what you're trying to do is to animate the right padding, then perhaps you should just do that directly.

If I put in a direct animation for the padding and change the starting value in the CSS, it starts to animate smoothly.  I'm not 100% sure I know what animation you were looking for, but this should be the direction you can go: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PE4qQ/.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// Animate the single page nav
    jQuery("a#post-nav-next").hover(function(){ 
        jQuery("a#post-nav-next span").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "1.0", "padding-right": "100px"});
        }, function() {
            jQuery("a#post-nav-next span").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "0", "padding-right": "0px"});
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I guess the width states should be 0 and full size (ie. expand to accomodate text. I guess i could toogle the width of the <a> (as it is set to be display: block) from 100px (as in example) to full width... but how???

Comment: See my additional comments on animating the padding.  Some inline elements don't like having the width forced.  You can do that with block elements like div or inline-block elements.  In that case, you'd have an initial state with a fixed width and a final state with a width of auto.  Again, I don't think you can do that with toggle("width") - I think you have to explicitly set the two states.

Comment: Yeah, all good points. I'm going to leave this for now, and go to bed (its 1:30 am in Melbourne). I'm going to re-examine in the morning. zzzzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 0):

After some time out I came back to have another go at this animation. The final effect can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Niels/zrru5/1/

Some important things to notice are the following:

1. The `overflow:hidden` rules hides text as it's container is animated.
2. `white-space: nowrap;` on the `span` prevents text reflow.
3. The `div` is left in its default state on load, and the width is stored. That width is then reapplied in the hover animation.

Someone better at this than me would make the js more concise, but there you have it. A nice effect for post navigation.